# Python attribute error

Tags: python

I am new to python and getting this error, please help me out correct it.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fft2'

Program

```
import numpy, scipy , pylab , wave , scipy.io.wavfile as wav 
xs = numpy.arange (1,100,.01)
rate , sample = wav.read("pianotest.wav")
fft2=scipy.fft2(sample) # algo applied
bp=fft2[:]  
for i in range(len(bp)): 
if i>=10:bp[i]=0  
ibp=scipy.ifft2(bp) # inverse algo
print"to check dimension"
print("sampling rate = {} Hz, length = {} samples, channels = {}".format(rate,   *sample.shape))
print(sample)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `scipy.fft2` **and** `scipy.ifft2`, do `scipy.fftpack.fft2`, or `numpy.fft.fft2`.

**Also, add `import scipy.fftpack2` to the top of your code, and then everything should work fine.**

Look [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft2.html) for more information on `scipy.fftpack.fft2` or [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html) for information on `numpy.fft.fft2`.

Here is your edited code:

```
import numpy, scipy , pylab , wave, scipy.fftpack, scipy.io.wavfile as wav 
xs = numpy.arange (1,100,.01)
rate , sample = wav.read("pianotest.wav")
fft2=scipy.fftpack.fft2(sample) # algo applied
bp=fft2[:]  
for i in range(len(bp)): 
if i>=10:bp[i]=0  
ibp=scipy.fftpack.ifft2(bp) # inverse algo
print"to check dimension"
print("sampling rate = {} Hz, length = {} samples, channels = {}".format(rate,   *sample.shape))
print(sample)
```

If it still isn't working, check to see if your scipy version is `0.14.0` by typing `python -c "import scipy; print scipy.__version__"` into your command prompt. If it doesn't show `0.14.0` or above, then upgrade your version of `scipy`.

Comment: still shows the same error as "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fftpack'"

Comment: Thank you, just need to add another line "from scipy.fftpack import fft2, ifft2 " at the top and it works fine

Comment: @user3699203 if this answer helped you, feel free to accept it by clicking the green check mark next to my answer. Full disclosure: it gives you +2 reputation :)

Comment: @aj8uppal next time, link to this post: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want either this [from SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft2.html)

```
scipy.fftpack.fft2
```

or the following [from NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html)

```
numpy.fft.fft2
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fftpack'

Comment: Are you sure you installed the `SciPy` module correctly?

Comment: Thanks, just need to add another line "from scipy.fftpack import fft2, ifft2 " at the top and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html) and [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft2.html) it should be either `numpy.fft.fft2` or `scipy.fftpack.fft2`, not `scipy.fft2`.